# Reading Writing to plist Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xcode, plist

I have seen quite a few questions about this but cant seem to find a one that fits my needs.

I have a plist that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Content</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>dateAdd</key>
            <date>2011-03-23T14:40:47Z</date>
            <key>content</key>
            <string>Content first</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Title 1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>dateAdd</key>
            <date>2011-03-23T14:40:47Z</date>
            <key>content</key>
            <string>Content here</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Title 2</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Im fetching the information from the plist like this

In the first class

```
//points to the plist
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *url = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Details.plist"];

    //filling with contents of plist
    NSDictionary *Data = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:url];
    self.contentData = Data;
    [Data release];
```

In the second class i create an instance of this class and fetch the information

```
Petite_NotesAppDelegate *instance = (Petite_NotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

self.dataArray = [instance.contentData objectForKey:@"Content"];
```

This makes it possible to get the content from the plist like this

```
NSDictionary *Content = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [Content objectForKey:@"Title"];
```

My problem is i am not able to write to the plist

Since the content i want to write is in the plist array Content and then inside the item 0 item 1 etc. How would i write to inside the content array in the plist? Lets say i want to write content from a textfield...

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: See if this helps.
[PropertyLists/Introduction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are probably trying to write to the same file that you read from. I'm afraid that's not possible - you are reading from the **application bundle** which is **read only**. If you want to save your changes to disk you need to write your dictionary to a plist located in the **Documents** directory.

To get the path to the Documents directory you need to do the following (there are other ways of doing this as well):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// you will read and write to this path
NSString *url = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Details.plist"];
```

This also means that when you start your application you should check to see if the **Details.plist file exists in your Documents directory**, if it does, read from it, otherwise **fall back to reading from the the application bundle**.

Comment: Thanks a lot that did it, I was reading from a different place and writing to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes to the dictionary and then use `writeToFile:`

[Sample](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1613-read-write-create-data-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

This can easly handle by deepcopy array

```
-(void) WriteOverSamePlist : (NSNumber *) num {
    NSString *appPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"storedRowIds.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *arr =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self ReadArrayFromPlist] copyItems:YES]; //[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"this", @"is" , nil];
    [arr addObject:num];
    BOOL fileExists = [arr writeToFile:appPath atomically:YES]; 

    if(fileExists) {
        NSLog(@"successfully written");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"failed to write");
    }
}


-(NSMutableArray*) ReadArrayFromPlist {
    NSString *appPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"storedRowIds.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *coolArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:appPath];
    return coolArray;
}
```